# integer division in Ruby with negative value

Tags: ruby, division

Trying to do a negative value division in Ruby, e.g. -123/10, why it returns -13 instead of -12 ?

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p375 (2013-01-18) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

irb(main):001:0> -123/10
=> -13
irb(main):002:0> -123%10
=> 7
```

-123/10 returns -12 and -123%10 returns -3 in C/C++ as expected.

Comment: The result of `-123 % 10` in C and C++ is, AFAIK, platform dependent so be careful about using the C behavior as your standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how it is designed. Ruby rounds numbers towards negative infinity in case of negative division and modulo operation. This is not unique to Ruby, Python and Perl behaves like that also.

However, this approach provides a good mathematical reason.

`a / b = q` with remainder `r`

such that

```
b * q + r = a and 0 <= r < b
```

From what I read, this is how arithmetic is taught in Japan.

**Edit:**

[sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314166/sawa) pointed out that this is how positive arithmetic is taught in Japan, not negative numbers. However, as he said, this can be extended to negative numbers as well.

Sources:

[Ruby Forums](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3289)

Comment: Your citation (as well as the original) is misleading. 1. That formula is indeed how it is taught in elementary schools in Japan, but it is not only in Japan. 2. Japanese elementary schools do no teach negative numbers. You get that behavior by extending the formula to negative numbers. Not because it was taught like that.

Comment: @sawa Updated my answer by taking your comment into consideration.

Comment: Ruby Forums link is dead :(